# read data from sdcard in android

Tags: android, file

I just wanna display the contents of files from sdcard on emulator (as image files/video files/music files like that).

Below is my code.

```
public class listfiles extends ListActivity {
 private ArrayList<String> item = null;
 private ArrayList<String> path = null;
 private String root="/";
 private TextView myPath;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sub);
        myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);
        getDir(root);
    }

    private void getDir(String dirPath)
    {
     myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);

     item = new ArrayList<String>();
     path = new ArrayList<String>();

     File f = new File(dirPath);
     File[] files = f.listFiles();

     if(!dirPath.equals(root))
     {

      item.add(root);
      path.add(root);

      item.add("../");
      path.add(f.getParent());

     }

     for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
     {
       File file = files[i];
       path.add(file.getPath());
       if(file.isDirectory())
        item.add(file.getName() + "/");
       else
        item.add(file.getName());
     }

     ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
     setListAdapter(fileList);
    }

 @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

  File file = new File(path.get(position));

  if (file.isDirectory())
  {
   if(file.canRead())
    getDir(path.get(position));
   else
   {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
    .setPositiveButton("OK", 
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       }
      }).show();
   }
  }
  else
  {
   new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")
    .setPositiveButton("OK", 
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       }
      }).show();
  }
 }
}
```

In my output I got file path & file name. But when i click the file, it won't show the contents. What should I do for that? Thanks

Finally i got it.My corrected code is shown below..

```
public class SDCardActivity extends ListActivity {
 private List<String> item = null;
 private List<String> path = null;
 private String root="/sdcard";
 private TextView myPath;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // Intent intent=getIntent();

        setContentView(R.layout.sub);
        myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);
        getDir(root);
    }

    private void getDir(String dirPath)
    {
     myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);

     item = new ArrayList<String>();
     path = new ArrayList<String>();

     File f = new File(dirPath);
     File[] files = f.listFiles();

     if(!dirPath.equals(root))
     {

      item.add(root);
      path.add(root);

      item.add("../");
      path.add(f.getParent());

     }

     for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
     {
       File file = files[i];
       path.add(file.getPath());
       if(file.isDirectory())
        item.add(file.getName() + "/");
       else
        item.add(file.getName());
     }

     ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
     setListAdapter(fileList);
    }

 @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

  File file = new File(path.get(position));

  if (file.isDirectory())
  {
   if(file.canRead())
    getDir(path.get(position));
   else
   {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
    .setPositiveButton("OK", 
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           dialog.dismiss();
       }
      }).show();
   }
  }
  else
  {
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + file.getPath());
      String fname=file.getName();
      if(fname.endsWith(".jpeg")||fname.endsWith("png")||fname.endsWith(".gif"))
      {
          intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
          startActivity(intent);
      }
      else if(fname.endsWith(".mp4")||fname.endsWith(".3gp"))
      {
          intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
          startActivity(intent);
      }
      else if(fname.endsWith(".mp3"))
      {
          intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/*");
          startActivity(intent);
      }
      else  
          try {
              EditText tv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tn);
              StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');

                    //Set the text
                    tv.setText(text);

                }
            }//try
            catch (IOException e) {
                //You'll need to add proper error handling here
            }//catch

  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I've missed it in your code but I could not spot any [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) in it. You have to call an `Intent` with the `ACTION_VIEW` flag for whatever file you want to be shown.

For instance.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + file.getPath());
intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

You simple create an instance of `Intent`, set the action which is `ACTION_VIEW` in our case. Then you create an `Uri` object by concatenating the path of your file object to `file://`. All you have to do now is setting the data and type on the intent by specifying the uri and a type string. In my example every image type. You could however just specify a certain image type. Once your intent is set up and ready you fire it off by starting an Activity with the intent as a parameter.

Android is going to take care of finding an appropriate application to display the data in the intent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But where i've to insert your code into mine.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I got it finally.

Comment: One more query.,In the above code i can able to display image files on emulator.Using the same code how can i display text documents,video file,audio file separately?Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 8):

Below code show you how to read the file content from the SDcard.simple insert one text file in Sdcard and implement below code in your program.

```
    try{
           File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/f1.txt");
           fileIS = new FileInputStream(f);
           BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIS));
           String readString = new String(); 
           //just reading each line and pass it on the debugger
           while((readString = buf.readLine())!= null){
              textdata.setText(readString);
              Log.d("line: ", readString);
           }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```