# Access image/audio/video files from program

Tags: android

I am new to android development and find it quite exciting. I am planning to write my own app. i am using eclipse IDE with andriod SDK plugin to develop the apps.

i want to access the image/video/audio files which are stored in internal/SDcard memory inside my java program. how can i do that? sample code or any link which explains the process will help me.

thanks in advance
sanakr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways, one way is to use intent like this,

[read data from sdcard in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633260/read-data-from-sdcard-in-android)

Second way is to use File class and specify the path and once you know the type and want to handle your way , you can implement it.