# How to retrieve data stored in external USB device in android?

Tags: android, database, speech, usb-drive, text-to-speech

I am doing a project in android for text to speech conversion.How can i retrieve speech files stored in an external storage device??

I first tried on an image and this is my code...And its not working..No error is shown..but nothing is displayed.This is my code

```
 package com.org.sd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SdcardActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/F/cameraman.bmp");
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);             


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find some solution in following link:

It has general format still you can get some idea about it...

Link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633260/read-data-from-sdcard-in-android)